# Socket Handler failed to connect Java

Tags: java, sockets, applet, ip

UPDATE: THIS IS A SIGNED APPLET

So, I have an applet, which during initialization, it will try to connect to the server ip. something like

```
handler = new SocketHandler("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", 5000);
```

The server is located in the united states. and I've been testing that it works fine (applet will load correctly) if the client is from United States.
but if client open the site from other country, the applet failed to load. it seems like it can't connect to server or something. Is there anyone know what's the problem or how to solve it. Do I need to use different IP address or something for international use?

UPDATE: Will there be anyway to increase the timeout connection? another thing that happen is that if I used slower connection, the java console with say timeout socket connection

Comment: It could be the server is detecting the source and refusing to allow connections from outside the US.  What is the site?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the site won't matter because you can't login.

Comment: *"the site won't matter"*  This is not a help-desk.

Comment: Without more details (Java console output, server information, server logs) you're unlikely to get much help with this.

Comment: @BeauGrantham the problem is there is no java console output, and server logs.. server information e.g it's windows server 2008, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-trusted Applet can connect only to server it was downloaded from for security reasons. So, check your java console. Probably you will find security exception there.

Other possible problem is that there is a firewall between your server and client.

BTW may I ask you why are you using TCP sockets for negotiations between applet and server? Why not web service, e.g. RESTful API over HTTP? At least this solves problems of firewall: if your applet was successfully downloaded using HTTP it will successfully talk to server using the same protocol.

Comment: this is a signed applet. I am using socket for writing a log file. since applet is on the client side, and I need to write the file on the server side, I need to use socket to openstream and write it on server.